# I don't know how to implement interfaces in Java

Tags: java, android

I have problems with opening an activity, I know that I have to implement interfaces to these interfaces of `OnClickListener`, `OnInitListener`. I have tried with `@Override`. In my android studio it says that I have to implement an abstract on `onclick()` method in `onclicklistener`. I am a newbie in programing so any help is much appreciated!

```
public void addGlossary(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent (this, addGlossary.class);
    Button buttonZero = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonZero);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

Here is the code for the activity:

```
public class addGlossary extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnInitListener {


    private int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 0;


    private TextToSpeech myTTS;


    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_glossary);


        Button speakButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.speak);
        speakButton.setOnClickListener(this);


        Intent checkTTSIntent = new Intent();
        checkTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
        startActivityForResult(checkTTSIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.button);
        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mMediaPlayer.start();
        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mMediaPlayer.stop();
            }
        });
```

When I have implemented those interfaces, and I try to connect to the activity my phone says that the application has stopped. I do not know what the problem is. Any help is appreciated.

What I implemented: onInit was already done

@Override

```
public void onClick(View v){
Button speakButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.speak);
speakButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

}

Comment: you want when buttonZero is clicked , addGlossary avtivity is opened?

Comment: start with something like this from programmers http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/179051/what-are-abstract-classes-and-abstract-methods

Answer (score 0):

You must implement **all the abstract methods** in **addGlossary** , add following code to the class,

[1) `onClick` for `OnClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html)

```
@Override
public void onClick (View v) {
    //do someting when the view clicked
}
```

[2) `onInit` for `OnInitListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.OnInitListener.html)

```
@Override
public void onInit (int status) {
    //do someting when tts onInit
}
```

[Click here to learn more about Java Interface.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html)